# How to reinstall an Eclipse plugin after its modification?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Sorry for the question but I'm at the end of my wits. I'm very far from Eclipse plugin development and Java in general.

Eclipse version - Juno.

I needed to customize DSF-GDB plugin of Eclipse-CDT. I downloaded CDT sources, created a PDE project, imported there `org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb` plugin, fixed configuration errors so that the project could be built. I did my change (removal of one baneful line) Then I exported my plugin via `Export...->Deployable Plug-ins and Features` and got my JAR file.

I've seen a couple of questions at StackOverflow regarding installation of such plugins so I put my JAR file under `dropins` folder. But it seems it hadn't been included for I didn't observe it neither under `About Eclipse SDK->Installation Details->Plugins` nor under Preferred Launchers (there was only the old one).

I thought probably it was because there could not be two instances of the plugin at the same time. So I tried to remove the original one from under `plugins` directory. It didn't help though, DSF-GDB integration disappeared completely.

How do I install my plugin properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've managed to do this. Thanks to @Chris Gerken for suggesting the direction of investigation.

First I tried to follow the advice of Chris but it didn't help. Then I decided to approach from other side and reinstall the plugin with *p2* platform. I used my plugin project, created a new feature project and an update site project so that I could select it in *p2* dialog box. I failed to install the plugin in this way because *p2* said that two versions of the same plugin could not be present at the same time. I wonder why didn't it offer me to choose between the one I wanted to install and the other that already had been?

Anyway I abandoned it and decided again to ask google. I came across [this wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started) and learnt that there existed a wonderful file called `bundles.info`. It contains the whole list of plugins in `plugin/` directory which should be picked up. I found there my plugin, changed its version, copied JAR file into `plugin/` directory and ran `eclipse -clean`. And voilà tout! Eclipse started to work with my plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse knows the current version of each installed plugin and will sometimes not make changes if a plugin is re-installed with the same plugin version or if the version changes but only minor metadata has changed.

So try:

- Increment the version number of the plugin
- Re-install by putting it in dropins
- Restart Eclipse with the -clean option

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't helped. Can the reason be in connection between the plugin and the feature which contains it? Do I need to change the feature too? And is there any way to examine Eclipse's startup process to see which plugins were picked up and which were not and why?